# Force `read_tsv` to decompress file

Tags: r, readr

I'm wondering if there is a way to get `readr::read_tsv` to read block gzip files with `.bgz` extension. I could rename the files to have `.gz` (which `read_tsv` automatically recognizes) which does work, but I don't want to do that everytime I get new files.

Thanks!

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the tip. That worked for me. Could you post it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a connection object rather than a file path. For example

```
read_tsv(gzfile("data.bgz"))
```

The gzfile() function will take any file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the file if it is a `bgz` via R:

```r
library(fs)
library(stringr)
library(readr)
# Regular expression to find your dataset file named datasetname
# You'll need to change that to the actual name
tsv_file <- dir_ls(".", regexp = "datasetname.*\\.b?gz")
if (str_detect(tsv_file, "bgz"))
    file_move(tsv_file, str_replace(tsv_file, "bgz$", "gz"))
dataset <- read_tsv(tsv_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did try something similar by renaming files using `mv` in shell.  But these files can be relatively large and shared with other users, so I would like to avoid renaming them.